# Making a lightweight app in BlackBerry Browserfield

Tags: java, mobile

This is an app made by me to display a web page on blackberry and to add some more features like checking network connectivity while opening app, loading some URL in browser rather than app, making a splash screen and loading animation.

The problem with the code is that when I run this app on blackberry device it after some time says "low memory on device. Please close some app" and this will close my app. I understand that this is a problem of browserfield as shown in [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Device-memory-is-Low-issue-for-an-WebWork-app/td-p/1166441). However I wish to make this code lightweight. This means none of the above features need to be compromised, but the amount of memory needed by the app need to be reduced so that app does not consume that much memory that it needed to be closed. I think above details are sufficient perhaps. I am ready to give further details as asked. this whole app was designed by me using Blackberry Eclipse plugin.

Can someone review this and suggest ways of making it lightweight?

**MyApp.java**

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
// Create a new instance of the application and make the currently
// running thread the application's event dispatch thread.
MyApp theApp = new MyApp();       
theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}



public MyApp()
{        
// Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
extracted();

pushScreen(new SplashScreen());
} 
private void extracted() {
new      ApplicationPermissions().addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INTERNET);
}
}
```

**MyScreen.java**

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen 
{

protected static boolean pageLoaded = false;
private BrowserField browserField;
private VerticalFieldManager mainManager;
private String targetURL = "http://reelafrica.net";


public MyScreen() 
{
createGUI();
 }

private void createGUI() 
{

mainManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR );
browserField = new BrowserField();
browserField = createBrowserField();

mainManager.add(browserField);

add(mainManager);


} 
private boolean checkURL(String mURL) {

 if(mURL.endsWith("?ultima"))
     return true;
return false;

}
private BrowserField createBrowserField() 
{      


boolean a= CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT);
     if(a==false)
     {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Dialog.alert("No Internet Connectivity");   
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

     }
     else{
PleaseWaitPopupScreen.showScreenAndWait(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        }
    });
     }

browserField.getConfig();
browserField.requestContent(targetURL);
ProtocolController controller = new ProtocolController(browserField) {
    public void handleNavigationRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception {


        PleaseWaitPopupScreen.showScreenAndWait(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {


            }
        });

         String x = request.getURL();
           if(checkURL(x))
           {
           BrowserSession b = Browser.getDefaultSession();
           b.displayPage(request.getURL());   
           }


      InputConnection inputConnection = handleResourceRequest(request);
      browserField.displayContent(inputConnection, request.getURL()); 

    }
};

browserField.getConfig().setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONTROLLER, controller);

browserField.addListener(new BrowserFieldListener() {


    public void downloadProgress(BrowserField browserField,ContentReadEvent event) throws Exception {

                super.downloadProgress(browserField, event);

        Application.getApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
            }
        });
    }

    public void documentLoaded(BrowserField browserField,Document document) throws Exception {
        super.documentLoaded(browserField, document);
        pageLoaded = true;
    }
});

return browserField;
}


}
```

**PleaseWaitPopupScreen.java**

```
public class PleaseWaitPopupScreen extends PopupScreen {

Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.WHITE, 0);
Border border=BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(5,5,5,5),Color.WHITE,Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT);
private AnimatedGIFField _ourAnimation = null;

private PleaseWaitPopupScreen() {
super(new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL |  VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR));
GIFEncodedImage ourAnimation = (GIFEncodedImage) GIFEncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("cycle.agif");
_ourAnimation = new AnimatedGIFField(ourAnimation, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
this.add(_ourAnimation);
this. setBackground(bg);
this.setBorder(border);

}


public static void showScreenAndWait(final Runnable runThis) {
final PleaseWaitPopupScreen thisScreen = new PleaseWaitPopupScreen();
Thread threadToRun = new Thread() {
public void run() {
    // First, display this screen
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(thisScreen);
        }
    });
    boolean mTest = true;
    while(mTest)
    {
    if(MyScreen.pageLoaded){
        mTest = false;
        MyScreen.pageLoaded = false;

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(thisScreen);
        }
    });
    } }
}
};
threadToRun.start();

}

}
```

**SplashScreen.java**

```
public final class SplashScreen extends MainScreen
{
public SplashScreen() {
super();
this.setTitle("loading...");
Bitmap obj = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("splashscreen480x360.png");
BitmapField headerLogoField = new BitmapField(obj, BitmapField.HFULL | Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
setTitle(headerLogoField);
add (new BitmapField(obj));
// add you splash screen images or whatever here

final SplashScreen me = this;
new Thread(){
public void run() {
    // do something that takes a long time
    try { Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (Exception e) {}

    synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
        Screen next = new MyScreen(); // replace with your next screen here
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(next);
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(me);
    }
}
}.start();
}
}
```

**AnimatedGIFField.java**

```
public class AnimatedGIFField extends BitmapField 
{
private GIFEncodedImage _image;     //The image to draw.
private int _currentFrame;          //The current frame in the animation sequence.
private AnimatorThread _animatorThread;

public AnimatedGIFField(GIFEncodedImage image)
{
this(image, 0);
}

public AnimatedGIFField(GIFEncodedImage image, long style)
{
//Call super to setup the field with the specified style.
//The image is passed in as well for the field to configure its required size.
super(image.getBitmap(), style);

//Store the image and it's dimensions.
_image = image;

//Start the animation thread.
_animatorThread = new AnimatorThread(this);
_animatorThread.start();
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics)
{
//Call super.paint.  This will draw the first background frame and handle any required focus drawing.
super.paint(graphics);
//Don't redraw the background if this is the first frame.
if (_currentFrame != 0)
{
//Draw the animation frame.
graphics.drawImage(_image.getFrameLeft(_currentFrame), _image.getFrameTop(_currentFrame), 
    _image.getFrameWidth(_currentFrame), _image.getFrameHeight(_currentFrame), _image, _currentFrame, 0, 0);
}
}

//Stop the animation thread when the screen the field is on is
//popped off of the display stack.
protected void onUndisplay()
{
_animatorThread.stop();
super.onUndisplay();
}


//A thread to handle the animation.
private class AnimatorThread extends Thread
{
private AnimatedGIFField _theField;
private boolean _keepGoing = true;      
private int _totalFrames;               //The total number of frames in the image.
private int _loopCount;                 //The number of times the animation has looped (completed).
private int _totalLoops;                //The number of times the animation should     loop (set in the image).

public AnimatorThread(AnimatedGIFField theField)
{
_theField = theField;
_totalFrames = _image.getFrameCount();
_totalLoops = _image.getIterations();

}

public synchronized void stop()
{
_keepGoing = false;
}

public void run()
{
while(_keepGoing)
{
    //Invalidate the field so that it is redrawn.
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            _theField.invalidate();                    
        }
    });                

    try
    {
        //Sleep for the current frame delay before the next frame is drawn.
        sleep(_image.getFrameDelay(_currentFrame) * 10);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException iex)
    {} //Couldn't sleep.

    //Increment the frame.
    ++_currentFrame;      

    if (_currentFrame == _totalFrames)
    {
        //Reset back to frame 0 if we have reached the end.
        _currentFrame = 0;

        ++_loopCount;

        //Check if the animation should continue.
        if (_loopCount == _totalLoops)
        {
            _keepGoing = false;
        }
    }
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should fix your indentation. I want to review the code, but a lack of indentation makes it really hard to read it.

You use Eclipse, so use this to format your code:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
>
> Or, in the main menu > Source > Format

---

Aside from that, there's a couple small things I see:

```
private int _totalFrames;               //The total number of frames in the image.
private int _loopCount;                 //The number of times the animation has looped (completed).
private int _totalLoops;                //The number of times the animation should     loop (set in the image).
```

You're indenting your comments.

To me, this is bad practice. I've been bitten by it before;

Someone writes a long line of code...

```
public static Object spliceIndex(List<Object> objects, int index){//Removes object from list. IMPORTANT: This function is 1-indexed!
```

And you miss the important stuff because you miss the last bit of the comment due to unfortunate sentence endings.

Don't indent your comments, and if you have a long comment put it on a separate line. I recommend putting it before the code, that's where javadoc comment blocks go anyway.

---

You put spaces after variables.

Specifically,

```
add (new BitmapField(obj));
```

and

```
this. setBackground(bg);
```

. To me, these disrupt my ability to identify what a word means. A space acts as a separator of "things" to me. And if you put a space between a function name and the arguments then I have to read it twice to understand what's going on.

Comment: Static analyses tools like Sonar report comments on the same lines as statement as a minor violation: comments should be on the previous line, not on the same line. I suggest to add this to your post ;-)

Answer (score 3):

#### `MyApp`

The name of this method doesn't seem to reflect what it does:

> ```
> private void extracted() {
>     new      ApplicationPermissions().addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INTERNET);
> }
> ```

Actually I don't get what it does at all.
Why create an object, call a method on it and then throw it away?

Will your program change if you delete this part?
If not then you should delete it.
If yes then you should add a comment,
because this code doesn't speak for itself, unfortunately.

#### `MyScreen`

Names like `MyScreen` are OK in throw-away test programs you write while learning a language.
As your program is starting to have some shape and complexity (which yours certainly does),
and definitely before sharing with others for review,
you should give it a better name.
The name should give a good idea to the reader what the class is about,
so I can guess what its responsibilities should be.

---

Is there a good reason for this?

> ```
> browserField = new BrowserField();
> browserField = createBrowserField();
> ```

The meaning of the first statement: *create a `BrowserField`*.

The meaning of the second statement: *create a `BrowserField`*? Uhm, what?

I also see that `browserField` is not used inside this class again:
after it's created, you add it to `mainManager`,
and the it's not referenced again.

When you don't need a variable as a class member,
you should use a local variable instead.
The same goes for `mainManager` too by the way.

This way would have been better:

```
private void createGUI() {
    BrowserField browserField = createBrowserField();
    VerticalFieldManager mainManager = ....
    mainManager.add(browserField);
    add(mainManager);
}

private BrowserField createBrowserField() {
    BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(); 
    // ... initialize / configure browserField as you did
    return browserField;
}
```

---

You can return boolean expressions directly, no need to wrap them with an `if`.
For example, instead of this:

> ```
> private boolean checkURL(String mURL) {
>     if (mURL.endsWith("?ultima"))
>         return true;
>     return false;
> }
> ```

You can write:

```
private boolean checkURL(String mURL) {
    return mURL.endsWith("?ultima");
}
```

#### More...

I only scratched the surface. There is so much more to review here,
and hopefully for you, other reviewers will chip it.

Optimize your programs for *read-time* convenience as opposed to *write-time* convenience.
Almost all code gets read more than it is written.
Even if (you think) you write it only for yourself.
Judging by the page stats, this question was read 66 times when I write this.

You haven't received answers since July 22 because this is very hard to read.
If you had taken the time to write it in a way that *you yourself* can read it easier,
it would have already been higher quality (I'm sure of it),
and you would have received far more, and constructive answers.

Bottom line: favor read-time convenience.
Review your code yourself first before posting here.
Apply the [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) technique, it does work.